# Casting to different Base classes gives different result. C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

Maybe my question is not perfectly formed, but my code will make everything clear.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{int n;};
struct B{int n;};
struct C : A, B{};

int main()
{
    C c;
    C* pc = &c;

    std::cout<<"TEST1"<<std::endl;
    cout << static_cast<B*>(pc) << "\n";
    cout << reinterpret_cast<B*>(pc)<<"\n\n";

    std::cout<<"TEST2"<<std::endl;
    cout << static_cast<A*>(pc) << "\n";
    cout << reinterpret_cast<A*>(pc)<<"\n";
}
```

And the output is:

```
TEST1
0042F830
0042F82C

TEST2
0042F82C
0042F82C
```

I know that using reinterpret_cast is ill formed design. I am not thinking about the design but the behavior is what bother me.
Can anyone explain why casting different ways gives different results the first time but the same result the second time??

Comment: The use of `reinterpret_cast` is almost always indicative of bad design. Avoid it and rethink the approach.

Comment: `static_cast<B*>(pc)` - "give me the location of the `B` part of `*pc`; `reinterpret_cast<B*>(pc)` - "treat `pc` as the location of a `B`".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This is actual answer, why don't you post it as such?

Comment: Is reinterpret_cast<> basically the same as a c-style cast?

Comment: @Zebrafish No, c-style casts could be any kind of cast. reinterpret_cast changes the type of the pointer without actual casting (the pointer address is not changed). You just interpret the same memory in a different way.

Comment: @Bizzarrus So if I have int* a; and I know I have a little endian machine, char* chptr = (char*)a; wouldn't necessarily point to the least significant byte of that int? I'm a bit worried because I've done this in the past to change endian order. I assume then that the c-style cast in C is completely different from the c-style cast in C++?

Comment: @Zebrafish Which byte of an int you get (LSB or MSB) is platform dependent. You can see how a [C-style cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) in C++ is interpreted.

Comment: @Zebrafish In this case, it will do what you want, yes. The problem with c-style cast is basicly, that the compiler chooses whether it uses reinterpret_cast, static_cast, or dynamic_cast, so you have to trust the compiler to know what you want. With basic types (int, char, etc), it will use reinterpret_cast (as far as I know), with complex types it might use dynamic_cast or static_cast. So explicit saying what cast you want can greatly prevent bugs and makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a class also means defining a memory layout. In its simplest form the members are laid out consecutively, e.g.

```
struct A {
    int n;
};
```

and in memory

```
| Address  | Size | Member |
|----------+------+--------+
| 0042F82C | 4    | n      |
```

The same happens with base classes

```
struct C : A, B {
};
```

potential memory layout

```
| Address  | Size | Member |
|----------+------+--------+
| 0042F82C | 4    | A::n   |
| 0042F830 | 4    | B::n   |
```

Now you have a pointer `pc` to an object of type `C`. Using [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) takes into account the layout of members and base classes within an object.

Therefore, you get the proper address for the `A` or `B` part.

Using [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) on the other side, just reuses a pointer and pretends it points to another type.

> **Explanation**
>
> Unlike static_cast, but like const_cast, the reinterpret_cast expression does not compile to any CPU instructions. It is purely a compiler directive which instructs the compiler to treat the sequence of bits (object representation) of expression as if it had the type new_type.

This is the reason, why you get the same address value.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, the `A` and `B` portions of `C` can't occupy the same space. One must come before the other. When you properly cast a `C*` to a `A*`, you get a pointer to the `A` portion of the instance that the original pointer pointed to, and the same is true for casting to `B*`. Since the `A` part of `C` (`int A::n;`) and the `B` part of `C` (`int B::n;`) are necessarily at different addresses, it's natural that the result of those conversions are also different from each other. This is possible because the compiler can know the layout of the object pointed to by `pc`, the information is deducible from it's type. This wouldn't work if the information wasn't available, for example if the pointer was cast to `void*` first.

The reason that `reinterpret_cast` gives the same address regardless of what you cast to is because that's specifically what `reinterpret_cast` does. It converts a pointer or reference to another type while disregarding any form of type safety. To `reinterpret_cast` a pointer is to create a pointer of a new type with the same address as the one provided, regardless of actual types and type safety.

Beware of using `reinterprect_cast`, as it essentially injects facts into the type safety system. The compiler is bound to assume that what you are telling it is correct. If those "facts" aren't true (like in the case of `reinterpret_cast<B*>(pc)`) you risk undefined behavior.